# Codeigniter 4 Pagination 404 File Not Found error

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, routes, codeigniter-4

I'm really struggling to overcome a 404 File Not Found error in CI4 since adding pagination to the Model function. I'm assuming it's to do with routing alone as it's also throwing up the same error on my `subbrand_name` page, which doesn't include any pagination in its Model code and was working fine until I added pagination to the `brand_name` page.

My Routes file:

```
$routes->get('shop/brands/(:segment)', 'Shop::brand_name/$1');
$routes->get('shop/brands/(:segment)/(:segment)', 'Shop::subbrand_name/$1/$2');
```

My Controller:

```
    public function brand_name($brand_name_slug)
    {
        $model = new ShopModel();

        $data = [
            'category_menu' => $model->category_menu(),
            'brand_menu' => $model->brand_menu(),
            'nav' => $model->nav(),
            'subnav' => $model->subnav(),
            'shop' => $model->brand_name($brand_name_slug),
            'pager' => $model->pager
        ];

        if (empty($data['shop']))
        {
            throw new \CodeIgniter\Exceptions\PageNotFoundException('Cannot find the news item: '. $slug);
        }

        echo view('templates/header', $data);
        echo view('shop/view', $data);
        echo view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
```

My Model:

```
    public function brand_name($brand_name_slug)
    {
        return $this
                    ->table('shop a')
                    ->select()
                    ->join('(SELECT sku, MIN(sale_price) AS sale_price FROM shop GROUP BY sku) AS b', 'a.sku = b.sku AND a.sale_price = b.sale_price')
                    ->where('availability', 'in stock')
                    ->where('a.sku !=', '')
                    ->where('brand_name_slug', $brand_name_slug)
                    ->groupBy('a.sku')
                    ->orderBy('brand_name, subbrand_name, product, size, unit')
                    ->paginate(15);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the url you're trying to hit while getting the 404?

Comment: www.seixwebdev.co.uk/shop/brands/hugo-boss

Comment: Also, haven't edited the .htacess file at all.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it was nothing to do with routing... just simply, my JOIN was buggy.

Managed to sort it by replacing `shop a` and `a.sku` in the JOIN part of the argument with `shop` and `shop.sku`. Worked perfectly... FINALLY!

```
    public function brand_name($brand_name_slug)
    {
        return $this
                    ->table('shop')
                    ->select('*')
                    ->join('(SELECT sku, MIN(sale_price) AS sale_price FROM shop GROUP BY sku) AS b', 'shop.sku = b.sku AND shop.sale_price = b.sale_price')
                    ->where('availability', 'in stock')
                    ->where('shop.sku !=', '')
                    ->where('brand_name_slug', $brand_name_slug)
                    ->groupBy('shop.sku')
                    ->orderBy('brand_name, subbrand_name, product, size, unit')
                    ->paginate(15);
    }
```